What is an inner product in terms of abstract algebra?
I'm trying to apply my knowledge of linear algebra to reinforce my understanding of general abstract algebra.
Since the output of a inner product is in a different form than the inputs (scalar vs vector), it cant be any form of operation in basic group or ring theory. So the only thing that would make sense to me are Domains and Fields, but my only justification for domains are fact that coefficients exist and my justification for Fields is that work on all real numbers instead of just integers. Basically no leads.
I've only studied up to field extensions so no lie algebras and am currently looking into modules to understand the topic better. My problem is that I have nowhere to start finding answers because I don't know what to ask and google didn't come up with any results.

It’s a bilinear form (in case we are talking about inner products on real vector spaces). I’m not sure what more you want said about this.

The definition of an "inner product" is given here, for example. All you need is a vector space $V$ over a field $K$. Then an inner product is a symmetric, bilinear map $V\times V\rightarrow  K$, which is positive definite (with $K=\Bbb R$).

This is a very good question, and it should not be closed for "clarity" issues.

@Trebor I am not sure that I understand the question correctly. For looking up the standard definition of an "inner product" you don't have to post this question. It is enough to look it up yourself. So what else is asked here? Why is it a good question? Read it again:"My problem is that I have nowhere to start finding answers because I dont know what to ask and google didnt come up with any results. What? I just googled the definition, where is the problem?

I think the positive-definiteness of the inner product is a bit hard to motivate from an algebraic perspective. You can do many interesting algebraic things with indefinite bilinear forms (See, e.g., special relativity), but a positive definite form is important because it induces a norm and hence a natural topology

You seem to be stuck because the output is different from the inputs. This is not unique to products. Consider the length of a vector or the magnitude of a complex number. There are many examples of functions that assign real quantities to things that are not real numbers. A course in physics or chemistry will provide you with many more examples.

I feel like the comments are getting off track. The OP’s question, as I interpret it, seems to be about finding some concepts in abstract algebra (which the OP seems to be effectively restricting to group theory, ring theory, and field theory) that correspond to inner products, in an effort to strengthen their understanding of abstract algebra. The OP seems to be under the impression that inner products should correspond to some “algebraic operation”, say a group operation or addition and multiplication in a ring. Unfortunately this is simply wrong. Inner products are their own algebraic…

… operation. It is a subclass of the more general concept bilinear forms. But it does not correspond to anything in group theory, ring theory, or field theory. If one insist, I suppose you can obtain a ring structure from it by taking the tensor algebra and quotient out by the relation $uv = \langle u, v \rangle$ (so a quotient of the Clifford algebra). Then the inner product effectively becomes the restriction of the multiplication operation. But it’s more that the multiplication comes from the inner product rather than the other way around.

@Waterbloo: Do you regard vector spaces over fields as being part of algebra? Because that is the proper setting of inner products. It also happends to be true that linear algebra is the general study of vector spaces over fields. It seems that you are reaching too far to find a setting or a meaning for inner products, even bothering to ponder some meaning in lie algebras etc., when the meaning is closer to home. Still, though, there are plenty of applications of inner products in many other branches of mathematics.

Well, there are a lot of things one could say, but I think it boils down to discussing how we layer structures on objects in abstract algebra.  Considering an $F$ vector space $V$:

$V$ is an abelian group with "extra structure" (maps that let you multiply elements of $V$ by scalars from $F$.)  You could also say this is an $F$ module, if you feel that qualifies as "algebraic object."
With this extra structure, you can define what linear transformations of $V$ are.  These transformations form a ring $R=End(V_F)$, and with that ring we can also think of $V$ has having a module structure, where the action of $R$ preserves the structure established in the last bullet point.  You see, the movement from "abelian group" to "vector space" is a kind of constraint that narrows our view from general group homomorphisms down to the subset that are $F$ linear homomorphisms.
Now we can also fix an inner product (a type of map from $V\times V\to F$, or equivalently, a linear transformation $V\otimes V\to F$ satisfying some axioms not listed here.) With this additional structure $V$ is said to be an inner product space, something more elaborate than a plain vector space.
Just like in the second bullet point, we can now investigate which transformations respect the additional structure.  This further narrows down the transformations under consideration to a smaller subset.  Nondegeneracy of an inner product necessitates that the transformations are nonsingular, so they no longer form a ring, but they do form a group.  Thus $V$ is no longer a module over this collection of transformations, but it is nevertheless a $G$-set where $G$ is the group of transformations respecting the inner product.

One intuition from the regular inner product on $\mathbb R^n$ is that the inner product encodes something about angles, and consequently distances.  This idea doesn't make any sense for general fields (think finite fields or even just $\mathbb C$), but it's sort of worth keeping in mind.
So, I would say that "algebraically" an inner product space is just a vector space with extra structure. Really the story being told here is the Erlangen program, where the interest is in studying groups of transformations preserving the constraint imposed (preservation of the invariant given by the inner product.)
As you can tell, the program uses all sorts of algebraic structures but perhaps the activity of studying invariances is a topic in its own right beyond "algebraic structures."  (The fact that inner products have "product" in the name is sort of a misnomer since it makes it sound like an operation.  As mentioned in the comments, that is not the case.)
More generally one could say the process of adding constraints is a natural operation when defining interesting subcategories of the category of vector spaces over a field, but the topic of category theory is perhaps best left for later, for you.
